# Matching partial URL regex Google analytics

Tags: regex, google-analytics

I want show only the URL's that contains "category-".

```
url/category-cats

url/category-elfs

url/category-dogs
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following can do the job :

```
^url/category-\w+/?$
```

But note that based on your regex engine you may need to escape the back slashe!

```
^url\/category-\w+\/?$
```

Comment: Thank you! It works!

Now i just seem to have another issue! 

Some of the URLs ends with a slash eg.

url/category-cats

url/category-elfs/

url/category-dogs

In the case above, only url/category-cats, and 
url/category-dogs are selected, not url/category-elfs/. 

Do you know how to solve this?

Comment: @MichaelKampmannRasmussen Welcome! you can put an optional slash there!

Comment: Its working thanks, now it just needs to show the pages where there is optional chars after slash 
url/category-cats/?ai=CATOUlgw9VfzkAunm7QbBqYKQDcvC6r0Gk-SfhdkBuv_WuLkBCAAQASgDYNGJxYL0B6ABrey82QPIAQGpAh7WjnVnjIM-qgQpT9C_kBp9KaiYMOt

The above is a google analytics split test url